# How I can validate response with Form Request and ajax json for laravel 8

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, forms

I have been using laravel for a short time, and I have been reading about good practices, I want to make an ajax json request with a validation in the form, I have seen that it is better to create a class "extend FormRequest" to better manage the information, in my case I am using validator but I don't know how to manage it in such a way to simplify the controller code as much as possible.

Currently I have:

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $messages = [
            'nombre.required'       => 'El campo nombre es necesario',
            'descripcion.required'  => 'El campo descripción es necesario',
        ];
        $rules = [
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'descripcion' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required|alpha_dash'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'errors' => $validator->messages()//$validator->errors()
            ]);
        } else {
            $crear = new Proyecto([
                'nombre'      => $request->nombre,
                'descripcion' => $request->descripcion,
                'url'         => $request->url
            ]);
            $crear->save();
            
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'message' => 'Registro insertado con éxito'
            ]);

        }
    }else{
        return view("404");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Proyecto extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
   protected $table = 'proyecto';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id_proyecto';
   protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'descripcion', 'url'];
   public function getRouteKeyName()
   {
       return 'url';
   }
}
```

js:

```
$('#crear_proyecto').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formu = $("#crear_proyecto").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "proyecto/crearproyecto",
        data: formu,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend:function(){
            $(".loader").show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#crear_proyecto').find('span.text-danger').remove();
            if (data.status == 400) {
                $.each(data.errors, function (key, error_value) {
                    $('#'+key).after("<span class='text-danger'>"+error_value+"</span>");
                });
                $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            }else{
                $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                alert(data.message);
                $('#crear_proyecto').trigger("reset");
                $("#nombre").focus();
                $('#modalformu').modal('toggle');
            }
        }
    });
```

I do not know if the code I have previously put is a bad practice or to leave it like that, what I have been seeing is to leave the controller as light as possible by creating a RequestForm, but I do not know how to adapt it with json and ajax, the idea was to do something like that:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
class PostProyectoRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'descripcion' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required|alpha_dash',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'nombre.required'       => 'El campo nombre es necesario',
        'descripcion.required'  => 'El campo descripción es necesario'
    ];
}
```

}

***EDIT***
Now I have this code in the controller:

```
public function store(PostProyectoRequest $request)
{
    $crear = new Proyecto([
        'nombre'      => $request->nombre,
        'descripcion' => $request->descripcion,
        'url'         => $request->url
    ]);

    $crear->save();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Registro insertado con éxito'
    ]);
}
```

And this y RequestForm

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class PostProyectoRequest extends FormRequest
{
 /**
  * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
  *
  * @return bool
  */
  public function authorize()
  {
     return true;
  }

  /**
  * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
  *
  * @return array
  */
  public function rules()
 {
     return [
         'nombre'      => 'required',
         'descripcion' => 'required',
         'url'         => 'required|alpha_dash'
     ];
 }

 public function messages()
 {
     return [
         'nombre.required'       => 'El campo nombre es necesario',
         'descripcion.required'  => 'El campo descripción es necesario'
     ];
 }
 protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
 {
    if($this->wantsJson())
    {
        $response = response()->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'errors' => $validator->errors()//$validator->errors()
        ]);
    }else{
        $response = redirect()
            ->route('guest.login')
            ->with('message', 'Ops! Some errors occurred')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    throw (new ValidationException($validator, $response))
        ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
        ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

}

Comment: I really like the failedValidation approach in your EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are actually right on track and you don't need to keep the old validation in the controller anymore. You want to do something like this.

```
//old 
//public function store(Request $request)

//new
public function store(PostProyectoRequest $request)
{
    $crear = new Proyecto([
        'nombre'      => $request->nombre,
        'descripcion' => $request->descripcion,
        'url'         => $request->url
    ]);
    $crear->save();


    //you can't have two responses because the first one would run only because 
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Registro insertado con éxito'
    ]);
    
    //or 
    
    $response = [
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Registro insertado con éxito'
    ];
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

So is instead of using the normal Request facade, you would use the form request PostProyectoRequest you created. By doing so, you are telling the controller to pass the request through the form request which would validate it and if any of the validation fails it, it would return a validation error and wouldn't run the code in the controller. [Read more about form requests here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) also read about [early returns](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.bestpractices.php) and returns in general

Comment: Thanks, I have left the code as you have put it, but when there is a failure I get the following message (Is this message normal?):

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
message The given data was invalid.

P.D: I have updated the code in the first message just below Edit.

Comment: yes, it is normal when the validation fails.  you would get the error message and what validation failed. so you just need to highlight the field or show the message on your frontend

Comment: With validator in controller the browser return this:
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]

But with RequestForm i hava this:
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity]

Why?

Comment: console log the response and paste it here. if it is failing now, it means your earlier validation wasn't validating properly. paste the response. also send screenshot of the filled form from frontend

Comment: I have found the solution after looking through the internet, I have updated the post, now it does not return any error, where is the method:
failedValidation

I give the issue turned out and I thank you very much for your help.